# Rename a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

Iam trying to get the HWND of multiple windows called the same, and i thought the easy way would be to rename the one i found and search again, but it seems iam not allowed to rename it the way i want.
This is what i have tryed

```
import win32gui
import win32api
test = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "notepad")
win32gui.SetWindowText(test, "testname")
```

Comment: import win32api
import win32gui

test1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, 0, "notepad")

test2 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, test1, 0, "notepad")

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my old project. may be this could help you. use this example as your reference

```
def UpdateControl_FromValue(self):
name_val = self.GetOptionValue(self.option_folder_name)
id_val = self.GetOptionValue()
self.in_setting_name = True
if id_val:
    self.SetOptionValue("", self.option_folder_name)
    opt_processors.FolderIDProcessor.UpdateControl_FromValue(self)
else:
    if name_val:
        win32gui.SetWindowText(self.GetControl(), name_val)
self.in_setting_name = False
```

Comment: Sorry i do not realy understand this, is self the hwnd? and i do not realy see where the new name is... sorry i am not that experienced.

Answer (score 0):

`FindWindow` can return an invalid handle (eg. when no windows matching the text is found). That could be your issue.

The win32gui module exposes `win32gui.EnumWindows` ([doc](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html)) that iterates top level windows. You can provide a custom callback that transform the window title.

In the following sample, I filter windows by title prefix, but you could implement a filter with regex, if that's more suitable for you.

```
import win32gui 

def f(hwnd, more):
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    # print(f"{hwnd} - {title}")
    prefix = 'notepad'
    if title.startswith(prefix):
        win32gui.SetWindowText(hwnd, title[len(prefix):])

win32gui.EnumWindows(f, None)
```